# Git merge with a patch

Tags: git, merge, version-control

My team is working on git branch BranchA that is branched off of branch BranchB being developed by another team. BranchB was merged to master, but not by using git merge (for some reason).  They created a patch and manually committed BranchB to master. Now we want to merge from master into ours, but git is understandably confused about the changes.  As far as it is concerned, just about everything is a conflict because it sees every change in BranchB as done independently of our BranchA.

I could repeat what the other team did: create a patch that diffs BranchA with BranchB and manually apply that as a separate commit on master. But I prefer for git to understand that I merged master into BranchB. That's effectively what I'm doing by applying a patch. Is there a way to get git to understand that a merge has happened after I apply this commit? In clearcase, you could manually draw a merge arrow indicating that a commit is a merge of two other commits, but I don't think you can do that in git.

Comment: Git doesn't track "changes"... each commit is a full copy of the code. "Changes" are determined by looking at actual diffs between files in commits. If it's saying that the files are different, then they are actually different in some way. Most likely, the white space characters have changed. That merge method would make it easy to accidentally commit stuff that you hadn't intended. For example, maybe the other devs were using a different OS and the line ends got changed, or maybe they converted tabs to spaces, etc.

Comment: a little bit of ascii art with the branches would be nice , 
where did B start from etc

Comment: How do you want to merge `master` branch into `BranchA`, just by git merge or apply the patch? And can you show the branch structure by graph in order to make the question more clearly?